# Expression for the line integral with respect to one of the coordinates

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, vector-analysis, line-integrals

> Avaluate the line integral $$\int_C(x-y^2)dx
> $$
>   over the curve $C:$ $y=x-\frac{x^2}{4}$, from $(0,0)\to(4,0)$.

In my textbook, the expression for a line integral over one of the derivatives is:

$$\int_Cf(x,y)dx=\int_a^b f(x(t);y(t))x'(t)dt$$
so it seems fair that if I take $x=t$, I'd change $y$ for the expression of the parable and the integral would just be:

$$\int_{x_1}^{x_2}(x-(x-\frac{x^2}{4})^2)dx$$

However, there's also another expression:
$$\int_C f(x,y)dx=\int_{x_1}^{x_2}f(x, y(x))\sqrt{1+(\frac{dy}{dx})^2}dx$$

Which yields a completely different result, so one of them must be wrong.

I'm just very confused here. Which one do I use and what's the difference between the two? Where do each of them come from?

Comment: typo. I've corrected it now

Comment: how so? (I'm asking because the exercise really has it go from (0,0) to (4,0), which are the two zeros of the curve)

Comment: They both do, tho: at $x=4, y=4- \frac{4^2}{4}=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parametrize the curve $ C $ as

$$x=2t$$
$$y=2t-t^2$$

the result is $$2\int_{t=0}^{t=2}(2t-(2t-t^2)^2)dt$$

Your last integral is given by
$$\int_{x_1}^{x_2}f(x,y)dl$$
which is a circulation along the curve and where $$dl=\sqrt{1+(\frac{dy}{dx})^2}dx$$

Comment: Oh, so the second one refers only to line-lenght, while the first is the one is for "normal" one-variable integration, right?

Comment: @Rye Yes {}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}